# How to check for a 10 digit number in a string

Tags: c, string, validation, formatted-input

In C, how do I check if a string read from a file contains a 10 digit number. I have used strspn and it seems to work, but I think there are better ways. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
char cset[] = "1234567890";
do
{  
// read line into line_string       
} while (strspn(line_string, cset) != 10);
```

Comment: loop through `isdigit()` `for (i=0;i<strlen(line_string);i++){if(isdigit(line_string[i])j++;} printf("%d", i);`.  Just saw @LihO's code.  Like his

Comment: I should add, there is _nothing wrong with using_ `strspn()`.  If you will notice, you get the results in 1 line, the rest of us used more lines to do the same thing :)  Kind of depends if you have a specific goal in mind.  "better way" is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Are you sure you read the `line_string` correctly?

```
char cset[] = "1234567890";
char line[] = "9846578497";
printf("%d", strspn(line, cset));
```

outputs `10`. A simple loop that explicitly checks every character is quite straightforward too:

```
int i, digits = 0;
for (i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; ++i)        // <-- make sure line is null-terminated
    if (isdigit(line[i])) digits++;
printf("%d", digits);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a much eaiser way, use the string.h library

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    char string[] = "0123456789";
    int stringLength = strlen(string);
    printf("%d\n", stringLength);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is if the number is stored in a char.

Comment: How do you know if it is a number by using strlen?, that gives the length of the string, but not the length of a _number_ within the string.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you wanted.

Let's presume a bunch of different inputs. For that we have:

```
char cset[] = "1234567890";

char str1[] = "5319764208";            /* all digits in different order */
strspn(str1, cset);    /* returns 10 */
char str2[] = "098765432";             /* not all digits present */
strspn(str2, cset);    /* returns 9 */
char str3[] = "not098a7654num321";     /* not a number, but has all digits */
strspn(str3, cset);    /* returns 0 */
char str4[] = "blah 1234567890 blah";  /* all digits in same order plus chars */
strspn(str4, cset);    /* returns 0 */
```

So it depends on what you intended acceptable input to be.

Comment: I can have strings e.g.
 
"blah 1234567890 blah" or "blah 3215556890 blah" or  "blah 5555667890 blah" etc

basically any combination of 10 digits plus chars together in a string, so I need to determine immediately if that 10 digit number is present.  

The fact that the following code returns 0 highlights the problem.

    char str4[] = "blah 1234567890 blah";  /* all digits in same order plus chars */
    strspn(str4, cset);    /* returns 0 */

Any better way than strspn?

Bob

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are many efficient ways but it depends how you are going to use them in your program. There are commands depending on your context of use, you can read on "strncmp" and "strstr".
If you want to compare for string in the starting of the line you can use,strncmp here is the example.

```
#define VALID_STRING "  <project"
#define COMPARELIMIT 10

if(!strncmp(linebuffer, VALID_STRING, COMPARELIMIT)) {
// your code goes here

}
else {

}
```

if you want to compare at any other point in the line buffer use "strstr"

```
#define CHECK_STRING "name="
    char *start=NULL; 
    start=strstr(linebuffer, CHECK_STRING);
    // it returns the address pointing to the first character of that(CHECK_STRING) string any where in linebuffer.
```